Imported sculpt brushes bulging and / or distorting mesh

As shown in the picture the imported / appended sculpt brush bulges the mesh outwards or erratically distorts it, sometimes both! As shown in the picture the brush is just supposed to stamp a bolt on the mesh.
The subject mesh has :

It's XYZ scales applied
Normals aligned outwards.
The topology remeshed with a voxel size of 0.005m
No non-manifold vertices, edges or faces

Yet the issue persists, i have included the brushes in the .blend file found here:
Updated :
This issue persists with all appended or imported textured brushes doesn't matter if they are made in the current file either. I have had this problem in past blender version too and I currently use Blender 4.0.1. Am I setting it up wrong? Or is this a bug?
Please Help.

Your blend file doesn't have the brush (bolt_screw_30_height.tif) so I can't even test your issue. Maybe packing your textures works for brushes ? Not sure.

@Lutzi I had packaged it with the file... but thanks for notifying...i'll upload an edited file

@Lutzi i have uploaded the updated blend file

I'm unable to reproduce your issue, your brush looks alright for me on Blender 4.1.1.

@Lutzi seriously? the f man! you think its a hardware thing? like lack of RAM or lower GPU specs? i got like 16GB and RX580 respectively...

Highly unlikely.
